# Custom modal transition style?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiviewcontroller

I was wondering if there is a way to have a vertical or a carousel effect style for model transition style? I'm switching between multiple views.

Comment: Unless it's one of the predefined styles you'll have to code it yourself.

Comment: There are many, many open source frameworks for this sort of thing.

Comment: The asker didn't ask for open source frameworks or 3rd party projects. My answer, although I admit doesn't really solve his problem, is still valid, since coding it yourself implies that someone else may have already coded it. No need for a downvote.

Comment: I completely disagree. The downvote is nothing personal, I just don't see this as a helpful answer particularly since he doesn't actually have to code it himself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iCarousel might suit your needs:

http://www.charcoaldesign.co.uk/source/cocoa

it's really good.

the four modal transition styles available in ios at present are:

```
UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl
UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal
UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical
UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a really good open-source solution over at github called HGMLTransitions:
https://github.com/Split82/HMGLTransitions

It's fast and built on OpenGL. Here's a video of it in action:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69TbdU5uJvU