# navigationController:pushViewController with special effects for iPhone transactions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

Usually we always push from one view to another view using the following method:

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];`

*`for some other animations we used :UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown / flipRight etc etc.`*.

All these are regular in use,

But **i want my app with different transitions**..

Any other custom transitions / special effects in transitions.. (Push/pop) or any other External api's for Animations..

Comment: Look for Custom UIModalTransitionStyle...
Some examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192730/custom-modal-transition-style

Answer (score 7):

You could use the **CATransition**:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 1.0;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
transition.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];
```

You can change the transition by: `transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;`

**Don't forget to add the Quartzcore framework!**

Comment: Awesome simple transitions. Thanks!